# Fim error while running synchronization. - Invalid credentials.

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, sync, credentials, fim

[image: Error] When i am running user profile synchronization, i am getting the below error in SharePoint 2013. The screen shot is from Synchronization service manager. How to resolve the below error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show what stage the sync failed, but my assumption is that it will be that you have incorrect credentials for your sync account. If you go to Central Admin -> Manage Service Application -> UPSA and edit your sync connection with the correct username/password.

Comment: Is there any process to change the username and password or we can just directly put in the valid credentials of any managed account?

Comment: Do not use a managed account. You should be using a dedicated account for the AD sync process.